How to make a quad face into a Ngon
i tried subdividing the face and messing with some vertices but that seems to not work, and I'm completely stuck on how to turn a square face into a circular face.

You'd need to subdivide it and, with the outer vertices selected, press Alt+Shift+S and drag the mouse. This will make a circle.
Finally, you'll want to press the Del key and delete faces.
The end result should look like this:

